# Making use of alphanum bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I just learned that the bibliography style alphanum is what I looking for to use in my text. But I am so beginner! It seems to me that one should download the related bst file (for the alphanum style); but I don't know where to save it on texlive directory (I know there is a bst folder in bibtex folder, but not more). 
Another question is that should I necessarily make use of bibtex? It seems too difficult to me. All my knowledge is to write a command like \bibliographystyle{alphanum} and make use a bib file which contains my references.

Comment: I suggest to use `biblatex` with the `alphabetic` style, as it is easier to customise if you have any special needs (it uses a latex syntax).

Comment: Most modern LaTeX environments will have the style already in and will take care of the `bibtex` run. If you have any problem, please state which LaTeX system you use, on which operating system, and which editor --- as well as a short, complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. It seem really that fundamental solution is biblatex. Sometimes I should try to be familiar with it.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you so much for your kind message. I changed thing a little bit, and it seems to be working right now.

Comment: The fundamental problem I had (which not noticed in the Question above), was that I am writing the text in Persian, and Persian is a language which is written from right to left. And so there are always issues with numbers and Latin text. The problem solved temporarily by the command \lr{\cite{}} instead of \cite{}.